# Who should be reliable for permissions check in a web app?

Tags: permissions

I am working on a project where you have controllers that expose an API and services that implement some logic.

In this project, each service* checks for the user's permissions to use the service.

When asked, I am told it makes life easier to the service's consumers because they don't have to bother themselves with permissions.

The code in this design looks like so

```
@Post
@Path('/addItem')
public Response addItem(@RequestBody Item item){
    itemHandler.add(item); // this call actually does the permissions verification
}
```

However, I am familiar with another design where controllers are responsible for permission checking before activating the service.

This design keeps the services simple and unaware of any permissions mechanism, and the liability for security lies on the consumer.

```
@Post
@Path('/addItem')
public Response addItem(@RequestBody Item item, Request request){
    if (hasPermissions(request)){
        itemHandler.add(item);  // is not concerned/aware of permissions. 
    }
}
```

I guess there are pros and cons for each. 
I am trying to find more material on the matter to decide if the current status in the project requires change or not.

*** service - meaning an object we are invoking.

Comment: I think this would depend entirely on your application. We'd need more concrete examples of how it works to decide whether the permissions check belongs in the controllers or services.

Comment: @Alternatex - I'll add any information you need. can you be more specific as to what I should add to the question?

Comment: In my personal experience the permissions check in a web application is always done at the controller level. Though there may be cases where in a given controller a service returns different results based on user permissions. I haven't come across such an edge case. Hopefully someone with a bit more experience will offer their advice. +1

Comment: @Alternatex thanks! do you know of any documents/posts, or a place of discussion around such designs where I can find more material to read on the matter?

Comment: I can't really help with that since it's off topic and I don't really have any useful suggestions. You could try to search this site and StackOverflow though, there must have been similar questions asked previously. For example, [here's one where I was wrong about permissions at the controller level](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/308479/154465).

Comment: I believe this is a JAX-RS app in Java.  Is that correct?

Comment: @JimmyJames not sure. maybe spring mvc? haven't worked in java for a while. new to the project.

Comment: Right.  The RequestBody annotation is Spring MVC.  JAX-RS has security functionality built-in.  Spring MVC probably has something similar.  It might help you to understand what Spring MVC brings to make your analysis more concrete.